# In R base plot, move axis label closer to axis

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have eliminated labels on the y axis because only the relative amount is really important.

```
w <- c(34170,24911,20323,14290,9605,7803,7113,6031,5140,4469)
plot(1:length(w), w, type="b", xlab="Number of clusters",
     ylab="Within-cluster variance",
     main="K=5 eliminates most of the within-cluster variance",
     cex.main=1.5,
     cex.lab=1.2,
     font.main=20,
     yaxt='n',lab=c(length(w),5,7), # no ticks on y axis, all ticks on x
     family="Calibri Light")
```

[image: cluster plot]

However, suppressing those tick labels leaves a lot of white space between the y axis label ("Within-cluster variance") and the y axis.  Is there a way to nudge it back over?  If I somehow set the (invisible) tick labels to go *inside* the axis, would the axis label settles along the axis?

Comment: Try leaving `ylab` out of `plot` and putting it in `axis` instead with some placing option. (Can't recall the options offhand.) I.e., `plot(...); axis(2, ...)`

Comment: I don’t think `axis()` controls the axis title. The `labels` in `axis()` are the labels on the tick marks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try setting `ylab=""` in your `plot` call and use `title` to set the label of the y-axis manually. Using `line` you could adjust the position of the label, e.g.:

```
plot(1:length(w), w, type="b", xlab="Number of clusters", ylab="",
     main="K=5 eliminates most of the within-cluster variance",
     cex.main=1.5,
     cex.lab=1.2,
     font.main=20,
     yaxt='n',lab=c(length(w),5,7), # no ticks on y axis, all ticks on x
     family="Calibri Light")

title(ylab="Within-cluster variance", line=0, cex.lab=1.2, family="Calibri Light")
```

[image]

Please read `?title` for more details.

Comment: Ah man, I was just about to post this exact thing. I had it all written out but I was trying to figure out why R on Windows wasn't letting me change the font. Anyway, nice work.

Comment: @sgibb thank you very much for teaching me that `title` can be used for labels (not just to set `main`).  I wound up using two `title` statements, one to offset `ylab` by `line=1` and one to get `xlab` a little closer at `line=2.2`.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 43):

Adjust `mgp`, see `?par`

```
title(ylab="Within-cluster variance", mgp=c(1,1,0), family="Calibri Light",cex.lab=1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: To move the axis title closer adjust `mgp[1]`. The default is 3.

Comment: More detail setting can be done by adjusting `mgp` parameters.

`mgp=c(3,1,0)` generally set 3 objects, which are: A) `title` margin line for the axis title (default 3), B) `labels` margin line for the axis labels (default 1)  , C) `line` margin line for the axis line (default 0). Thanks