# Remove space between axes and text

Tags: r, plot, axes

Good evening everybody,
I'm getting about a problem with a multiple boxplot in R.
I would like to remove the space between the numbers on the y-axes
and the axes itself. I don't want to move the label, with mtext(),
and it's not a problem with the margins par(mar()).

Thank you very much here there is an example: I would get the numbers (-1,1) closer to the axes.

[image: [my plot]]

Comment: the graphical parameters are under `?par`, I think you want to change the middle value of `mgp`: `plot(1:5, mgp = c(3, .5, 0))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In R base plot, move axis label closer to axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265728/in-r-base-plot-move-axis-label-closer-to-axis)

Comment: Those are NOT 'boxplots'.